# Accessing Node.js app on LAN Server by alias instead of IP address

Tags: node.js, iis-7, alias, iisnode

I have Node.js app running on Windows Server. As of now it can be accessed by:

```
http://<ip address>:3000
```

I would like users to access it using something like:

```
http://my.nodejs.app
```

I am struggling to figure out the proper configuration of IIS. I came across iisnode but it looks like that package is no longer being maintained.

Comment: That's right. You shouldn't use iisnode any more. But you can set up reverse proxy rules on IIS to forward traffic from `http://my.nodejs.app` to `http://<ip address>:3000`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: You can use a reverse proxy to redirect `http://my.nodejs.app` to `http://<ip address>:3000`, and then create host record in the hosts file.